# Executing multiple queries at once

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

I'm using `EntityFramework` to work with `MS SQL` database.

In my database I have table `users` and three tables `A`, `B`, `C` containing users data. Each of them has column `version` of `row-version` type (database is updating this record with larger number when the row is updated).

User is sending me version of his data - one number: `userVersion`. As response I need to send him data from these three tables where `version` is higher than `userVersion`. I can do this using three queries:

```
var listA = Entities.As.where(... && a.version > userVersion).toList();
// 1
var listB = Entities.Bs.where(... && b.version > userVersion).toList();
// 2
var listC = Entities.Cs.where(... && c.version > userVersion).toList();
```

and then I need to send user current version:

```
userVersion = Max(listA.Select(a => a.version).Max(),
                  listB.Select(b => b.version).Max(),
                  listC.Select(c => c.version).Max());
```

The problem is that when I've got `listA` db could be updated with newer version of `As` and `Bs`. So when I've got `listB` the version of `listB` is newer than version of `listA`.

At the end user will get `userVersion` so high that he never will get element updated in "`query`"

Example (I'm writing only `version` column)

1. A = `{1, 3, 6, 8}`, B = `{2, 5, 9}`, C = `{4, 7}`, `userVersion=3`.
2. `listA = {6, 8}`.
3. Now another query from another thread is executed adding element `10` to `A` and `11` to `B`, so B = `{2, 5, 9, 11}`.
4. `listB = {5, 9, 11}`.
5. `listC = {4, 7}`.
6. `userVersion = 11` and user will never get element `10` of `A`.

Is there any way to prepare these three queries (one per list) and thene execute them at once so no updates or inserts will be done between?

Comment: I can think of a transaction that blocks writing to As, Bs, Cs. But that might be very bad for performance.

Comment: Do you only need the max or do you also need the contents of each lis?